# django deprecation warning location

Tags: python, django, testing, deprecated

I am getting a deprecation warning while running tests for an app that I have installed/used in a django site. The deprecated feature is django/utils but the actual file that was using the deprecated feature is not given. Is there a way to get django to tell me which file is giving the deprecation warning or do I have to manually go through every single file in the app to find the reference? I am still new to testing in Django so I appreciate the help very much.

Comment: what is the full text of the warning?

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/hashcompat.py:9: DeprecationWarning: django.utils.hashcompat is deprecated; use hashlib instead
  DeprecationWarning)

Comment: It looks like I might have asked a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266765/django-track-down-causes-of-deprecationwarning?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Run python using error warnings to give you full traceback:

```
python -Werror ./manage.py runserver # or whatever command gave the error
```

and you should be able to track down where it's coming from.

---

The dupe you mentioned will also work.

Comment: my output for that is:
`DeprecationWarning: django.utils.hashcompat is deprecated; use hashlib instead
`

Comment: I ended up using `grep hashcompat *` to track down the source of the error manually