# SubfieldBase has been deprecated. Use Field.from_db_value instead

Tags: python, django

```
/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py:22: RemovedInDjango110Warning: SubfieldBase has been deprecated. Use Field.from_db_value instead.
  RemovedInDjango110Warning)
```

Since I upgraded to Django 1.9 I started having this warning on `runserver` startup. The problem is that I have no idea where it comes from. I am guessing it must be from `forms.py`. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Are you using third party apps or creating your own db fields?

Comment: Yeah, I am using model-utils. https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/setup.html#installation I posted the problem there but the creator said it could be something on my project.

Comment: You don't have any other 3rd party apps? I know this is one that's currently showing up in django-timezone-field, for example.

Comment: Many third party apps are not fully compatible with Django 1.9. I suggest using Django 1.8.7 while 3rd party apps catchup.

Comment: I made a test and uninstalled the app (I had just started using it) and I still can see the problem. It must be somewhere else.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266765/django-track-down-causes-of-deprecationwarning) for tracking down the causes of warnings.

Comment: I added but it doesn't seem to be triggering in the pages I am entering. I saw someone mentioning on `python-social-auth` he had the same problem. I believe it is coming from there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I experienced this error while using `python-social-auth 0.2.13`. If you are using `python-social-auth`, I submitted a fix for this on [GitHub](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/pull/813), just now. This extends another fix submitted [here](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/pull/806).

Subscribe to both of those pull requests and if/when both pull requests are merged into the `master` branch, you will no longer see the warning.

Comment: How do I download this fix with pip? The change has not been reflected on pip's repository.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't download it via pip until the maintainer merges the pull request and submits a new release to PyPI.

Comment: I tried `pip install git+HTTP_MASTER_BRANCH` and it worked. The only problem is that it seems to be the same as in pip. Is this command the same as `pip install app_name`?

Comment: Try to install from https://github.com/contracode/python-social-auth/tree/fix-django110-warnings-2